# What does params keyword in method signature really mean

Tags: c#, arrays, parameters

I'm skimming through Troelsen's Pro C# 2010 and came across the discussion of the params keyword method modifier. Reading the text, MSDN, and other tubez sources, it seems to me the only thing you get from params is the ability to pass a comma delimited list of values to the method. I wrote some code to prove to myself that I can send arrays of different lengths to a method that does not use the params keyword, and everything works just fine.

Now, I'm all in favor of saving keystrokes when it makes sense. In this case, however, I suspect the savings is illusory, and confusing to those who have to maintain code. Illusory because I'm never going to send a hard-coded list of values to a method (bad form!). Confusing because what's a maintainer to make of a method that lists a bunch of values rather than an object that explains what I'm doing?

OTOH, since the most of the folks at MS, and most of the folks here, are smarter than I am, I suspect I'm missing something. Please, anyone, enlighten me!

Thanks.

Comment: So in one line you : When and what is the practical use of params in a real world? is that what you are trying to ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you ever used [`Console.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h)?

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}: The value of {1} is {2}.", lineNumber, foo, bar);
```

This sort of call is where `params` can be useful. Having to explicitly construct an array to contain your parameters is just noise which makes the code harder to read without adding any value. Compare to the how it would look if `params` weren't used:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}: The value of {1} is {2}.", new object[] { lineNumber, foo, bar });
```

The second version adds no useful information to the code, and moves the values further from the format string, making it harder to see what is going on.

Comment: Convenient: yes.  More attractive/more readable: certainly.  But fundamentally *different*?  I don't think so.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4: Opinions aren't required; look at the generated MSIL.  It is equivalent, `params` is syntactic sugar.

Comment: Something doesn't need to be fundamentally different for it to be useful. Another classic example of params usage is `string.Join(",", param1,param2,param3,etc...)`. Without changing the string.Join method, you could also do `string.Join("&", myStringArray)`

Comment: The Console.WriteLine example makes it much clearer to me. The examples in the book, and elsewhere, being pedagogical devices did things like passing numbers to a CalculateMean function. Doing something like that -- passing values rather than variables and objects -- gets my best-practices knickers in a bunch. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is easier for me to type:

```
SomeFuncWithParams(a, b, c);
```

Than it is to type:

```
SomeFuncWithParams(new object[] { a, b, c });
```

And if you think syntactic sugar is not a good reason to implement a feature then you'll also need to start questioning the validity of properties, the `using` statement, object initializers, etc.

Comment: I often duplicate such methods with the `IEnumerable<T>` equivalent. This allow to pass either one T, or any number of T, or an enumerable of T.

Comment: @SteveB: But that's not quite the same.  `params` is for a finite number of method/function parameters.  `IEnumerable<T>` is for a collection of arbitrary size.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: yes, I use two overloads. Example : `public void Foo(IEnumerable<int> values) { /* Process all values */ }` and `public void Foo(param int[] values) { Foo((IEnumerable<int>)values); }`. This allows you to pass either `Foo(42);` or `Foo(42, 20000001);`, or `Foo(myDataContext.Customers.Select(c=>c.Id));`. I use such signatures often in utility classes. No requirement for calling code to convert values from/to array of values (calling .ToList() or building an array with fixed values)

Comment: The only reason to use a IEnumerable overload is if you want to do processing on the elements as they come (i.e. from a data reader) rather than receiving the entire set at once. Otherwise, you could save some code and an overload by just doing `Foo(myEnumerable.ToArray())`

Comment: Most of time, you don't have to worry about the executing sequence.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, I've always thought of the .Net "params" keyword as the moral equivalent of C/C++ variadic arguments.
2. No, I can't think of any way that "params" and a variable-length array aren't completely equivalent.

Comment: And if you look at the MSIL they are actually equivalent.